# Add document with auto-generated ID in sub collection?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to add a document with auto-generated ID in `reviews/something` using:

```js
await addDoc(collection(dbFirestore, "reviews", route.params.id), {
  rating: rating,
  text: text,
  user: {
    id: user.id,
    username: user.username,
    avatar: user.avatar,
  },
});
```

But I get:

> Invalid collection reference. Collection references must have an odd number of segments, but reviews/XXX has 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume reviews is a collection and want to add a document (with auto generated id) to its subcollection

```
await addDoc(collection(dbFirestore, "reviews/document_id/subcollection"), {
  rating: rating,
  text: text,
  user: {
    id: user.id,
    username: user.username,
    avatar: user.avatar,
  },
});
```

Comment: This actually works, I didn't know that I can do this only on sub-collections, I thought I can do it in documents as well. In that case I'll just do it like this: `"reviews/posts/" + route.params.id`. Thank you for your help!